# Add a variable to a table in MonetDBLite

Tags: r, dplyr, r-dbi, dbplyr, monetdblite

Here is mtcars data in the MonetDBLite database file.

```
library(MonetDBLite)
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

dbdir <- getwd()
con <- dbConnect(MonetDBLite::MonetDBLite(), dbdir)

dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "mtcars_1", value = mtcars)

data_mt <- con %>% tbl("mtcars_1")

dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE mtcars_1 ADD COLUMN new=2")
```

How should I add a column/variable "new" to the table mtcars_1 in the MonetDBLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE mtcars_1 ADD COLUMN new_col INTEGER DEFAULT 2")`

Comment: @Hannes Mühleisen Thanks! Then, how should I create new_col=mpg/cyl? I tried, dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE mtcars_1 ADD COLUMN new=mpg/cyl") , but its throwing an error.  Where can I read more about these functions?

Comment: dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE mtcars_1 ADD COLUMN new_col2 DOUBLE PRECISION")
dbSendQuery(con, "UPDATE mtcars_1 SET new_col2=cyl/mpg")  This worked...just wondering if this can be done in one step...otherwise it's fine.